# Download zip fil and unzip it using Alamofire in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have a zip file of assets in AWS S3 bucket. I want to download that zip file using Alamofire and unzip and save in my device. I am using Swift. Please help.

```
func downloadFile(url : URL, completionHandler: @escaping(NSDictionary?, Error?) -> Void){
        let destinationPath : DownloadRequest.Destination = { _, _ in
        let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0];
        let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("Assets.zip")
        return (fileURL, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
    }
    AF.download(url, to: destinationPath).responseData { response in
        print(response)
        switch response.result{
        case .success(_):
            print ("sussessfully Downloaded")
        case .failure(_):
            print("download failed")
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: can you please share any downloadble link so i can give you answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all need to install pod
**https://cocoapods.org/pods/Zip**

Then

```
import Zip
```

Download function call

```
    self.downloadPdf(pdfReport: webLink, savePathURL: finalDestinationUrl) { (pdfFilePath, status) in
        
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: pdfFilePath){
            
            
            try? Zip.unzipFile(pathUrl, destination: finalUrl ?? validUrl, overwrite: true, password: nil, progress: { (progress) -> () in
                print(progress)
                
                
            })
            
        }
    }
```

Download function definition

```
func downloadPdf(pdfReport: String, savePathURL: URL, completionHandler:@escaping(String, Bool)->()){
    
    let downloadUrl: String =  pdfReport
    let destinationPath: DownloadRequest.Destination = { _, _ in
        return (savePathURL, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
    }
    debugPrint("downloadUrl=>",downloadUrl)
    AF.download(downloadUrl, to: destinationPath)
        .downloadProgress { progress in
            
        }
        .responseData { response in
            print("response: \(response)")
            switch response.result{
            case .success:
                if response.error == nil, let filePath = response.fileURL?.path {
                    completionHandler(filePath, true)
                }
                break
            case .failure:
                completionHandler("", false)
                break
            }
            
        }
}
```